# reachabilityWithHostName Example

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

i read the https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html
my Question is if the www.apple.com is become not active Suddenly..this code will alert me?
or just if my connection fail's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's absolutely right.

It will fire off a `kReachabilityChangedNotification` notification that tells you the new reachability state.

You get the new reachability state something like this :

```
- (void)reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
    Reachability *reachability = notification.object;

    if (NotReachable == reachability.currentReachabilityStatus)
        NSLog(@"No longer reachable");
}
```

Comment: you sure that this code check with the host if their is connection and in the moment that the connection is Ok i will tells me? can i change the time that he check it? ( and what is the default time? )

Comment: (1) Yes, this will check a host, assuming that's how you created your `Reachability` object. (2) You can't change the time it polls to check. Because it's more complicated than simple polling. Continually asking a server if it's there would kill the battery life - there's better techniques and shortcuts that iOS will be taking (3) There's not a default time - in fact, even if it were polling, it probably wouldn't be the same time interval each poll.