# is Reachability is update in realtime (reachabilityWithHostName)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [reachabilityWithHostName Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217964/reachabilitywithhostname-example)

i have this code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(reachabilityChanged:) name: kReachabilityChangedNotification object: nil];
hostReach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"www.apple.com"];
[hostReach startNotifier];    

- (void) reachabilityChanged: (NSNotification* )note{
Reachability* curReach = [note object];
NSParameterAssert([curReach isKindOfClass: [Reachability class]]);
}
```

my Questions is:
if www.apple.com will not respond from some resone, the reachabilityChanged function will be automatic called?

Comment: In the first line of the code you have posted you add `self` as an observer to the `kReachabilityChangedNotification` notification, meaning that `reachabilityChanged:` will be called when ever a reachability changed notification is posted.

Comment: i am sorry but i do not understand your answer :( i understand that reachabilityChanged will be called but how can i check if the server is really not respond

Comment: I don't understand your question, the whole point of reachability is to check if a host is reachable, or if your connected to the internet at all. Why would you double check it then?

Comment: The answer is in your earlier question - the notification object is a Reachability object, which you can query for further status information about the connection.

Comment: ok i got it.. sorry and thank u guy's